# what are the jsp dependencies need to add in spring maven project?

Tags: java, spring, maven, jsp, servlets

My project has error to compile **jsp** file with jstl/core taglibs
and I think some dependnecies have not been added to the pom file
Does anybody know what are the jsp dependencies I need to add in my project?

I added these dependecies in my pom file

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

thank you for helping

Answer (score 0):

Replace first dependency with the following :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

I think this was the minimum to compile JSP.

Comment: i replaced first dependency but cuased jsp unable to compile error

Comment: Remove all dependencies and put only this one. Then Maven -> clean install  -> alt  + F5 -> OK

Comment: i removed all and then clean and build but jsp unable to compile again

Answer (score 0):

Go to the .m2 repository and delete the /javax/servlet folder.
Then clean and update the project by going to Project > Right Click > Maven > Update Project.

Comment: i cleaned and updated in maven > update project but still jsp unable to compile error is: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
 java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
 org.gjt.xpp.impl.tokenizer.Tokenizer.next(Tokenizer.java:1274)